# Add postinstall rule for deb package creation

Tags: catkin, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get a fork of the [pr2-grant](https://code.ros.org/svn/pr2debs/trunk/packages/pr2/pr2-grant/) released for our ros_ethercat package as we find it very useful. In the pr2 repo, there were some post-install rules to set the sticky bit of **pr2-grant**.

Is there a way to do this with catkin / bloom?

Below is the debian/postinst rule

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
PKG=pr2-grant
case "$1" in
 configure)
   chown root.root /usr/bin/pr2_grant
   chmod +s /usr/bin/pr2_grant
   chown root.root /usr/bin/pr2-grant
   chmod +s /usr/bin/pr2-grant
   ;;
 *)
       echo "postinst called with unknown argument \`$1'" >&2
       exit 0
   ;;   
esac
#DEBHELPER#
```

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191779/add-postinstall-rule-for-deb-package-creation/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Bloom` allows you to patch the generated Debian files at your will. So yes, you can add whatever post-install rule you would like.

The comfortable thing is that `bloom` will automatically reapply your patch for future releases.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2014-09-03**:
great thanks

**Comment by [Subhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/88794/subhi/) on 2021-11-03**:
Hello, would you please provide some detailed information about how to do that using Bloom, thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To build on @Dirk Thomas's answer, you can add your post install rule amongst the `debian` folder template files and it will get copied over (unmodified) into each OS version specific branch for Ubuntu.

For example, you would add your file to this branch:

https://github.com/ros-gbp/openni2_camera-release/tree/debian/indigo/openni2_camera/debian

So in this case the branch name is `debian/indigo/openni2_camera`, which contains the generic templates for all debian/ubuntu release targets. Then the files which end in `.em` in this branch get their templates expanded and copied into version specific branches, e.g. `debian/indigo/trusty/openni2_camera`. If you put your files into the `debian/indigo/openni2_camera` branch without a `.em` extension they will just be copied over.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2014-09-04**:
Thanks for the clarification William!